# Jquery - Multiplying my two classes give no results

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiplication

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="jumbotron" id="group">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="groupNumber">Group:</label>
        <input type="text" class="groupNumber" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group inputTop">
       <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
       <input type="text" class="quantity" />
      </div>
     <div class="form-group inputTop">
       <label for="systemPrice">System Price:</label>
       <input type="text" class="systemPrice" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="groupTotal">Group Total:</label>
       <input type="text" class="groupTotal" />
     </div>
   </form>

   <div class="row specs" id="pasted" contenteditable="true"></div>

   </div>
 </div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.inputTop input').keyup(multInputs);

  function multInputs() {
    $('.inputTop').each(function() {
        var $quantity = $('.quantity', this).val();
        var $systemPrice = $('.systemPrice', this).val();
        var $groupTotal = ($quantity * 1) * ($systemPrice * 1)
    $('.groupTotal', this).text($groupTotal);
    });
   }
});
```

JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/waynebunch/jh6uhL1p/5/

I've been staring at this for a while and am not seeing anything wrong.  Basically, I'm trying to use JQuery to multiply `var $quantity` by `var $systemPrice` and have the result displayed in `var $groupTotal`.  There will multiple "groups" of these.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, or if I'm way off?  Thank you!

Comment: FYI, you don't need: `($quantity * 1) * ($systemPrice * 1)`. You can just do `$quantity * $systemPrice`, since either way the multiplication operator will automatically convert the strings to numbers.

Comment: @squint you are correct, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
$('.groupTotal', this).text($groupTotal);
```

With:

```
$('.groupTotal', this).val($groupTotal);
```

Comment: I hate when it seems so easy.  Thank you, this fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$('.groupTotal', this).val($groupTotal);
```

given that `.groupTotal` is an `input`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this function :

```
 function multInputs() {

$('.group').each(function() {
  var $quantity = $('.quantity', this).val();
  var $systemPrice = $('.systemPrice', this).val();
  var $groupTotal = (parseInt($quantity) * 1) * (parseInt($systemPrice) * 1)

  if(isNaN($groupTotal))
    $('.groupTotal', this).val('');
  else
    $('.groupTotal', this).val($groupTotal);  
});
```

I hope you will get result which you want

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others have said (using `val` instead of `text`), you're also calling the `each` method on the wrong selector.

The elements with class `quantity` and `systemprice` are **not** children of the elements with class `inputtop`. Instead, use

```
$(".form-inline").each( ... );
```

Comment: Got it, thank you!  That definitely helped with my cloning of the groups it looks like.